# How to count invisible items with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I can count **visible** items by using `filter` like this:

```
it('should have correct number of visible columns', function () {
  expect(tableHeaders.filter(function (header) {
      return header.isDisplayed()
  }).count()).toBe(6);
});
```

But how do I better count **invisible** ones?
This one doesn't work as the `header.isDisplayed()` returns a Promise, not just a boolean:

```
it('should have correct number of visible columns', function () {
  expect(tableHeaders.filter(function (header) {
      return !header.isDisplayed()
  }).count()).toBe(6);
});
```

So, how should I count invisible items the most Protractor way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to use [`.reduce()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce) for this purpose:

```
    expect(tableHeaders.reduce(function (acc, header) {
      return header.isDisplayed()
          .then(function (isDisplayed) {
              return acc += !isDisplayed ? 1 : 0;
          })
    }, 0)).toBe(7);
```

I increase the accumulator variable by `1` if the item is not displayed then return it and compare to the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

`reduce()` can be used here, but [`.filter()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) would be "the most Protractor way":

```
var invisibleTableHeaders = tableHeaders.filter(function (header) {
    return header.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
          return !isDisplayed;
      })
});
expect(invisibleTableHeaders.count()).toBe(7);
```